# Create a simple multidimensional object array and assign to cookies

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a shopping cart for anonymous users which are stored in a cookie on the users computer. But I am confused.

Here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                var PID = $('#Input_Product').val();
                var Qty = $('#Input_Qty').val();
                var P = $('#Input_Price').val();

                var data = { ProductID: PID, Quantity: Qty, Price: P };


 $("#btnWrite").click(function () {
                    // $.cookie("Name", $("#txtName").val());
                    document.cookie = "Product='+PID+'; expires=Friday, 20 Sep 2019 01:00:00 UTC; path=/ ;";
 document.cookie = "Quantity='+Qty+'; expires=Friday, 20 Sep 2019 01:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
 document.cookie = "Price='+P+'; expires=Friday, 20 Sep 2019 01:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
                });
```

What I am trying to achieve is get a multi dimensional object array and assign the values of the shopping basket to a cookie or multiple cookies.

Also Being new to javascript, how do I retrieve the values on the client side. I know I can use stringify to post to the server

I tried initializing it with but getting errors

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
 data[i] = new { ProductID: PID, Quantity: Qty };
alert(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: `localStorage` would probably be better. Convert it to JSON and store it in LS.

Comment: @localstorage  what is LS ?

Comment: LS is an abbreviation for localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Cookie Way**

Cookie can't store spaces or commas, and you can only store one key-value pair per assignment statement. You could separate each value and assign it to a cookie, like this:

```
document.cookie = "Product=+PID+;"
document.cookie = "expires=+DATESTRING+;"
document.cookie = "path=+PATH+;"
```

However, whenever you assign another cookie like this, the previous cookie's `path` and `expires` will be overwritten. The better way is to encode all the data into a cookie safe string:

```
document.cookie = "Product=+PID+DATESTRING+PATH+;"
```

Then you can look up the product and parse each of the arguments using a `.split('+')`.

**The Modern Way**

Cookies have several drawbacks when compared to localStorage. Two of the most impactful being that (1) the cookies in the browser are sent over every http/s request (potential personal information leak) and (2) cookies have a limit of 4KB of data storage, localStorage allows 5MB (significantly more!).

To use it in the way you wanted here, you could do something like this:

```
// setting it:
localStorage.setItem('Product', '+PID+DATESTRING+PATH+')
// getting it: 
const productData = localStorage.getItem('Product').split('+')
const productId = productData[0]
const productDate = productData[1]
const productPath = productData[2]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot Jacob, I however used a different method. I use JSON.Stringfy and JSON.Parse to set and retireve the values, many thanks